# Do not make copy of existing file in destination folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been trying to copy contents from one folder to another folder in google drive using google app script. With some online help and documentation of google script, I was able to copy files from one folder to other but it copies all files from source folder to destination folder on time trigger, but I want only the new files to get copied in my destination folder and skip the present files that are already same in my source and destination folder.

I tried to check files by name before copying but couldn't find a way to compare files by name in two different folders of gdrive.

```
function CopyFiles() {

  var SourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Sid');

  var SourceFiles = DriveApp.getFolderById('Sid').getFiles();

  var DestFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Did');

   var DestFiles = DriveApp.getFolderById('Did').getFiles();

  while (SourceFiles.hasNext())  
  {
    var files = SourceFiles.next();

    var dfiles = DestFiles.next();

     if ( files == dfiles){

    file.setTrashed(true);}

   else{

      var f = files.makeCopy(DestFolder);

    }

  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that Script compares files by name in destination folder and if files by that name already exist than skip else, create a copy of that new file in the destination folder.

Comment: `file` is not defined in your code.

Comment: What files if any do you wish to trash?

Comment: no, I just want the same files in both folders. Like for example the destination folder is my backup folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Copies files from source to destination if destination does have the same file names**

In this version no files get trashed.

```
function CopyFiles() {
  var srcFldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('srcId');
  var srcFiles=srcFldr.getFiles();
  var desFldr=DriveApp.getFolderById('desId');
  var desFiles=desFldr.getFiles();
  var dfnA=[];
  while(desFiles.hasNext()) {
    var df=desFiles.next();
    dfnA.push(df.getName());
  }
  while(srcFiles.hasNext()) {
    var sf=srcFiles.next();
    if(dfnA.indexOf(sf.getName())==-1) {
      sf.makeCopy(sf.getName(),desFldr);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Cooper, the code is giving me that error.   ReferenceError: "dfnA" is not defined. (line 13, file "Copy Files")

Comment: Try it again.  I made some changes.

Comment: One last change.  I tested this and it works okay and keeps the same names

Comment: Yeah, I tried it again. but it deletes the content from my source folder. If I create a new file in source folder and runs the script it copies the file into destination folder but removes the previous files from the source folder.

Comment: If it has the same file name in destination folder, it deletes the same file names from source folder.

Comment: What is the behavior you expect?  It's not clear from your question or your code what behavior is expected.  I am essentially moving files from source to destination when they don't exist in the destination...based upon filename.

Comment: I have two folders. source folder and destination folder. I manually create some files in source folder and wants them to be copied in the destination folder after some time of the creation, for which I use a trigger. What I basically need is that the script compares the file name in both folders and creates a copy of only those files by name which doesn't exist in the destination folder.

Comment: So you don't wish to trash any files.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes, I want the same files in both folders, but as of my code when I was copying, it was creating files by the same name rather than just only creating the new files from source folder. In your solution, I changed ```sf.setTrashed(true);``` to ```  df.setTrashed(true); ``` which does keeps the files in both folders but one less in destination folder than actual source folder.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: In my code there is no association between df and sf.  They are in different iterator loops.

Comment: I've two folders. One is shared folder and One is backup folder. My shared folder(source) in which users upload their files and documents and with time to time I need these files and documents  to be updated in my backup folder(destination) by using time trigger. Previous code is not comparing the file names in both folders and just simply copying the same files with new files on time trigger. Due to which I,ve been having same file in my destination folder many  times rather than for just once.

Comment: yeah, i understand that it has no association.

Comment: Of course, the problem with that is that having the same name doesn't necessarily imply having the same content unless your files name include a timestamp string.

Comment: If you understand that there is no association then why would you want to trash df?

Comment: I don't want to trash files, I just want the files to be copied from source folder into destination folder, I set it to trash because i wanted only a single copy as the script runs after some time it again makes a new copy of already existing file in the destination folder which i dont want.

Comment: Okay we seem to have gotten off track here.  Let's return to my answer. What else would you like it to do or not do?  The last version just makes copies if the the file name doesn't exist in the destination.

Comment: Cooper, It works fine for me. It was me having some confusion. It worked well for me now. Thanks a lot for the help mate.

Comment: Great.  Glad to help.  Sorry for the confusion.